# Warp asks for absurdly long and complex explicit type annotations, is there another way?

Tags: types, rust, type-annotation, rust-warp

I'm getting the following error,

```rust
error[E0283]: type annotations needed for `warp::filter::and_then::AndThen<warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<impl warp::Filter+std::marker::Copy, impl warp::Filte
r+std::marker::Copy>, impl warp::Filter+std::marker::Copy>, [closure@src/http.rs:12:13: 24:4]>`
  --> src/http.rs:12:4
   |
9  |     let create_user = warp::post()
   |         ----------- consider giving `create_user` the explicit type `warp::filter::and_then::AndThen<warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<impl warp::Filter+std:
:marker::Copy, impl warp::Filter+std::marker::Copy>, impl warp::Filter+std::marker::Copy>, [closure@src/http.rs:12:13: 24:4]>`, with the type parameters specified
...
12 |         .and_then(|user: super::user::User| async move {
   |          ^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
   |
   = note: cannot satisfy `_: reject::sealed::CombineRejection<Rejection>`
```

This is what I wrote. I'm confused at how this is supposed to look,

```rust
pub async fn users() -> impl Filter<Extract = impl warp::Reply, Error = warp::Rejection> + Clone {
  let create_user = warp::post()
    .and(warp::path::end())
    .and(warp::body::json())
    .and_then(|user: super::user::User| async move {
      match &user.id_user {
        None => {
          if let Ok(u) = user.insert().await {
            Ok(warp::reply::json(&u))
          }
          else {
            Ok(warp::reply::json(&"FOO".to_owned()))
          }
        }
        Some(_) => Ok(warp::reply::json(&"FOO".to_owned())),
      }
    });

  let routes = warp::path("users");
  routes.and(create_user)
}
```

How is this supposed to look, am I really supposed to use an explicit type like,

> warp::filter::and_then::AndThen<warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<impl warp::Filter+std::marker::Copy, impl warp::Filter+std::marker::Copy>, impl warp::Filter+std::marker::Copy>

Just to be clear what I want here, is a create user end point.

- I want a user object to be deserialized from JSON
- I want to be able to reject the request (HTTP error) if that user object after deserialization has an id. I don't want the user to be able to choose the ID.
- `&user.insert()` will insert the user object in the database, and return a new user object with the ID.
- I want the either an error or the user object to be returned to the user.

How can I make sense of the absurdly complex type annotations that Warp is requesting? Is this really required, or am I making mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is failing type inference for the async block in the `and_then()` closure. There is no `Err()` path which would tell the compiler what the `Error` variant would be, thus the inference fails. You can fix this by annotating the full `Result` type on one of the return branches:

```
Ok::<_, warp::Rejection>(warp::reply::json(&u))
```

For additional reference:

https://users.rust-lang.org/t/async-function-parameter-results-in-type-annotation-error/45379

and a workaround for similar issue about using `?` in async blocks:

https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/07_workarounds/02_err_in_async_blocks.html